# Using Python / Selenium to read options

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm having trouble pulling information from a table using Selenium.  The HTML looks something like this:

```
<select id="software_version" name="software_version" onchange="CheckDropDownValueUIUpdate('software_version', 'software_version_image','software_version_message', 'Software Version');" style="visibility: visible;">
<option value="none">
Select a Version</option>

<option value="1732732">
12</option>

<option value="456456">
14.0.69</option>

<option value="68767">
13.62</option>

<option value="678934">
22.0.33</option>
</select>
```

Right clicking and selecting X-Path on Chrome for the 14.0.69 would return:

```
//*[@id="software_version"]/option[3]
```

So I put it in my code:

```
try:
    query = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="software_version"]/option[3]')
    SoftwareVersion = query.text
    print(SoftwareVersion)
    
except NoSuchElementException:
    new_row = {'Software': dfSoftwareName, 'Version': "Not Available"}
```

This yielded no result.

So I did a little reading and learned about selectByIndex and tried this:

```
try:
    query = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="software_version"]')
    query.selectByIndex(3);
    SoftwareVersion = query.text
    print(SoftwareVersion)

except NoSuchElementException:
    new_row = {'Software': dfSoftwareName, 'Version': "Not Available"}
```

But this yielded the result "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'selectByIndex'".  At this point I don't know where to look since the first option gave me no feedback.  Thank you for any suggestions you can provide.

Comment: try `Select(query).selectByIndex(3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And then you can locate an option like this:

```
options = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='software_version']/option")))
```

You can print the full list of options:

```
print('options:', [x.text for x in options])
```

Or you can print an individual one:

```
print('Third from the list:', options[2].text)
```

You can filter them by text:

```
the_one_youre_searching = [x for x in options if '14.0.69' in x.text][0]
```

You can get their attributes:

```
value_attribs = [x.get_attribute("value") for x in options]
```

Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: I feel like this is very close. When I use the code: print('options:', [x.text for x in options]). I get the output: options: ['', '', '', '', ''] and there are only give options. Going to similar links with various versions will have a similar output, but scaled to the number of options. For some reason it still isn't pulling the text from within.

Comment: Can you confirm the url? If you're not getting the value of the options, then maybe the HTML is different from what you posted. Code works. @Acuity -- Or maybe you're not using WebDriverWait?